# Where is the code for the "Proceed To Checkout" located?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am learning Magento 1.9.

I would like to see and learn from the the code of the **"Proceed to checkout"** button.

In which template is this code located?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it located at

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml
```

and

```
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml
```

An easy way to find a path of the file is Searching for the keyword in you project folder.

Comment: If you satisfied from this answer then please accept it.it will help to other people to find a correct answer.

Comment: Yes. 8 minutes are minimum required

Comment: I have made some change it will help to find other files.

Answer (score 1):

You can on your path hint from admin and heck the template and its block for all section of the page.

1. Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer
2. Select the store from `Current Configuration Scope` drop-down from top left section below navigation.
3. Than go to Debug -> Template Path Hint and set it to Yes.
4. Refresh the fron-tend page, You will get the all page path.

In this way you come to know if any custom module install and override any `phtml` then also you will get the path of that file.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use external Magento extension like

1 [Magento developer toolbar](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/developer-toolbar.html)

2 [Easy Template Path Hints](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html)

All above extension can display you template path and other information also.

Comment: For non-production system (stage/development box) you are able to turn on template path hints when you go to Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer. I would also turn on the Block Names (often very helpful).

Comment: Yes i know that but this tool are also good and help him more

Answer (score 1):

The chosen answer is appropriate for the question... but its essentially giving you the answer without telling you HOW to get the answer if a similar question comes up for something else.

I use a developer extension that runs on my local system that allows me to dynamically load up info such as template path hints, etc...

Add an event observer for: controller_front_init_before

And in your observer model, you can add the following code:

```
// enabling on-the-fly template path hints
if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->has('__hints')) {
    $store->setConfig('dev/debug/template_hints', 1);
    $store->setConfig('dev/debug/template_hints_blocks', 1);
}
```

Then for any URL, you can tack on ***?__hints*** to show the hints.

You can also do a number of other modifications... such as:

```
// enabling on-the-fly theme change to "base/default"
if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->has('__base')) {
    $store->setConfig('design/package/name', 'default');
    $store->setConfig('design/theme/template', 'default');
}
```

**NOTE:** you do not want to run this on a production system (live server) as it could compromise the system.