# Where is "buy now" button?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Where is the code for "buy now" button ?

In which template ?

I want to paste that code in some another page

Comment: by default magento 1. 9 dont support for `buy now` button ,  check this once : http://blog.fusedwebspace.co.uk/adding-buy-now-button-to-magento-1-9-that-skips-the-shopping-cart/

Answer (score 2):

You can on your path hint from admin and heck the template and its block for all section of the page.

`Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer`

Select the store from `Current Configuration` Scope drop-down from top left section below navigation.
    Than go to `Debug -> Template Path Hint` and set it to `Yes`.
    Refresh the fron-tend page, You will get the all page path.

In this way you come to know if any custom module install and override any phtml then also you will get the path of that file.

Comment: I know the path. But on that path there is only "Add to cart" button. I want "Buy now" button which directly adds product and go to checkout page, without viewing cart

Comment: then your question should be how to add buy now button

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it located at

```
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/catalog/product/**
```

An easy way to find a path of the file is Searching for the keyword in you project folder.

**OR**

You can on your path hint from admin and heck the template and its block for all section of the page.

`Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer`

Select the store from Current Configuration Scope drop-down from top left section below navigation.

Then go to `Debug -> Template Path Hint` and set it to `Yes`.

Refresh the front-end page, You will get the all page path.

In this way, you come to know if any custom module install and override any phtml then also you will get the path of that file.

for more information on template path go to [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142324/where-is-the-code-for-the-proceed-to-checkout-located/142325#142325)

Answer (score 0):

Add to cart page template path is:

> app/design/frontend/namespace/theme/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
// to call "add to cart" on any page
<?php 
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); // pass product id 
echo $this->getlayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```